# Excel - DSUM With Criteria In Column

Tags: excel

I am looking for a solution where I can use something like DSUM, but have 1 heading and the criteria from each row being in that row.

For example:

```
=DSUM('All Data'!A1:J999, 'All Data'!F1, B1:C2)
=DSUM('All Data'!A1:J999, 'All Data'!F1, B3:C3)
```

The first one works because it is getting the column headers in B1 and C1 and matching the value, but the 2nd row won't work because it doesn't know the column heading to match to.

I am looking to match two sets of criteria.

Is there any way to do a function like this without having to list column names each row?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into sumifs? (available in excel 2007/2010) Otherwise, you can look into sumproduct.

Comment: SUMIFS works great!  I only knew about SUMIF, which didn't give me multiple criteria.  Thanks!  I upvoted your comment and posted the answer for future people to see (can't accept for 2 days), but if you want credit for the answer, please post and I will accept yours.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into sumifs? (available in excel 2007/2010) Otherwise, you can look into sumproduct.

Answer (score 1):

Using SUMIFS like lionz suggested above works:

```
SUMIFS('All Data'!$F$1:$F$999,'All Data'!$A$1:$A$999,B2,'All Data'!$A$1:$A$999, C2)
SUMIFS('All Data'!$F$1:$F$999,'All Data'!$A$1:$A$999,B3,'All Data'!$A$1:$A$999, C3)
```

and so on.